# AppScan result shows an error of Client Cross Frame Scripting Attack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkmarx

AppScan of mycodebase shows a medium error of Client Cross Frame Scripting Attack

Here is the code snippet,

```
/index.html
Line no: 1
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are seeing this because you have not implemented counter-measures to prevent the page from being rendered in an iframe but there could be other reasons for the finding.  The remediation help in AppScan Source for the finding should provide HowTo guidance to resolve the issue.  You can also find more information on OWASP at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Frame_Scripting.

Scott Hurd